# Integrate FosFacebookBundle without FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

is it  possible to integrate `fosfacebookbundle` without `fosuserbundle`

I find this Documentation but it's not clear [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-basic-usage.md)
Anyone can help me to do it buy  giving me the  steps to integrate `fosfacebookbundle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say in their docs that the bundle is deprecated use  [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)  instead

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle#deprecated